# Usage of web service in ASP.NET web application

Tags: web-services, soap, asmx

To some this could be stupid question. But here's the deal. I have asp.net web application and I use jquery to call functions inside *.aspx.cs files that have [WebMethod] attribute attached to them. I had no clue that [WebMethod] is mainly using in web services. I never have worked with web services and I saw I can add .asmx file to my project. So from application architecture point of view where should I use and how can I use .asmx files, and if is it mistake to have [WebMethod] attribute inside *aspx.cs files.
Thanks :D:D

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're stuck using .NET 2.0, you shouldn't do either one. .asmx files are now considered by Microsoft to be a "legacy technology". All new web service development should use WCF. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf/info.

Answer (score 0):

you are rushing for a solution. it not that simple, read articles returned by a search term such as "asp.net web service" or "wcf web services"

and decide how you want to proceed

it will take some time to understand, say one to two weeks..